# Failed to create environments Cloud9 Amazon Web Services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloud9

I am currently trying to create a Cloud9 Environment with an IAM User with AdministratorAccess

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "*",
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
```

}

But every time, I get one of the following error:

[image: Environment Error 1]

or

[image: Environment Error 2]

I am creating the Cloud9 Instance on the us-east-1 server. And this problem has been happening for a couple of days now. Does anyone know the root cause?

Comment: What's the actual error coming from CloudFormation for the instance creation failure?

Comment: @Paolo, the only clue about the error are those pop-up messages...  Is there any other information for me to acquire?